# How can I get Azure container state from command line?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I wonder how I can filter by the 'State' of the container group from the command line (`Get-AzContainerGroup` or `az container list`).

In azure portal this field is reported as '**Status**'.
[image]

But I can't get it from the command line, it seems this field is not provisioned.

```
Get-AzContainerGroup | fl
ResourceGroupName        : rg-foo
Id                       : /subscriptions/foo/resourceGroups/foo/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/test-01
Name                     : test-01
Type                     : Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
Location                 : westeurope
Tags                     : {}
ProvisioningState        : Succeeded
Containers               : {test-01}
ImageRegistryCredentials : {}
RestartPolicy            : OnFailure
IpAddress                : 20.82.63.136
DnsNameLabel             :
Fqdn                     :
Ports                    : {80}
OsType                   : Linux
Volumes                  : {}
State                    :
Events                   : {}
Identity                 :
```

I've tried :

```
Get-AzContainerGroup | Where-Object {$_.State -eq "Succeeded"}
```

But as field seems was reported, it didn't work.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, please give me a couple of days to validate it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the **Status** column/property that you see on the Azure Portal actually translates to `properties.instanceView.state` for an [Azure Container Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-state).

It seems like this property isn't populated although present in the ouput of `Get-AzContainerGroup | fl *`. However, when the `ResourceGroupName` and `Name` parameters are passed along, you'd see **it shows up**!

Digging a little deeper, this is because the `Get-AzContainerGroup` cmdlet invokes the [Container Groups - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/container-groups/list) REST API under the hood, that does not have the `instanceView` property in the response.

Whereas, `Get-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName <Resource-Group-Name> -Name <ContainerGroup-Name>` calls the [Container Groups - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/container-groups/get) REST API that returns all the extended properties as well.

So, to work around this behavior, you can run the following snippet:

```
# List all container groups in the current subscription
# Equivalent to [Container Groups - List]
$AllContainerGroups = Get-AzContainerGroup

# Initialize an empty array to hold all container group objects with their extended properties
$AllContainerGroupsExtended = @()

foreach($ContainerGroup in $AllContainerGroups)
{
    # Gets a specific container group
    # Equivalent to [Container Groups - Get]
    $ContainerGroupExtended = Get-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName $ContainerGroup.Id.Split('/')[4] -Name $ContainerGroup.Name
    
    $AllContainerGroupsExtended += $ContainerGroupExtended
}

# You can now filter the result as needed
$AllContainerGroupsExtended | Where-Object {$_.InstanceViewState -eq "Stopped"}
```

Comment: Probably this will be the right answer! The proposed solution seems to work, and apparently it solves the problem. But it requires two calls... one to get the list of containers names and another one to get the container details... It's a pity I can't do it with only one call!

Comment: @arturn Glad you found the solution helpful! I'll reach out to the PS team to check on this behavior. Meanwhile, please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your problem so it also helps others in the community with similar queries. :)